# Creating docker images from puppet for jenkins

Tags: php, docker, jenkins, puppet

I'm currently trying to set up some continuous integration testing for the company I work for. System is LAMP based web application and I'm trying to get jenkins set up to do some continuous integration testing.

Current stumbling block is finding a docker image to run jenkins within PHP, most of the images I've found are out of date (haven't been updated in a year) and then don't work when you try to run through the jenkins setup.

We currently have a puppet configuration for our production servers and my current line of thinking is to use [puppet image build](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-image_build) to create a docker image based on our production set up; with the added bonus of like for like testing.

The problem here though is that we don't want to install jenkins on all our production servers. **Is there a way to add jenkins to a created docker image?** (preferably via CLI). And am I tackling this the right way or am I putting the cart before the horse i.e. **should I be looking at trying to put PHP on a working jenkins image?**

Answer (score 1):

Where I work, we have a... *few* lines of puppet that we maintain, and we've been discussing internally leveraging the existing puppet in docker, but how? I know nothing of the project you've referenced here, but it's a but of a bad smell that the project has sat dormant for nearly a year without a commit. We're taking a hard look at [HashiCorp's Packer](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/docker.html#dockerfiles)—for your purposes, the free and open source should do just fine!

But, to the second half of your question, the cart is probably before the horse right now. I'm confused as to what you're trying to accomplish with installing Jenkins *inside* the docker image to conduct your testing. I think what you're looking for is a longer-running jenkins server (with or without slaves) to run through setting up, running unit tests, integration tests, and so on. If you have the resources, gitlab-ce with gitlab-ci is a pretty simple way to get started in developing an on-premise ci/cd workflow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We found the easiest way to install Jenkins was through Docker but like you say it might be easier to set up Jenkins on a stand alone server on it's own rather than within a Docker image.